# Show a warning for an upcoming maintenance on every page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application. Before deploying a new version of my application to the server I want to inform my clients about the downtime a few hours before. That's why I want to show a small dialog on every page in my web app.

It should look something like this:
[image]

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign warnicon"></i>
    Upcoming maintenance from @Model.MaintenanceBegin to @Model.MaintenanceEnd. 
</div>
```

Of course I don't want to manually add this snippet to every page, that's why I considered using a _layout.cshtml which could be included in every view. The problem is that I already have a bunch of _layouts (for different purposes) and I don't want to add it in those files manually as well (as far as I know it's not possible to nest layout files).

**Question:**
Is there any suggestion how I could solve this problem? Or is there any better approach to this kind of problem?
I thought about using an `ActionFilterAttribute` which could intercept requests and append the messages to the response, but then I would have the overhead for each request.

Comment: You could include a `@Html.Action()` in the Layout to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` server method that returns a partial view of your 'warning'. It would return `null` typically, but a partial view if appropriate

Comment: That would work, thanks for the suggestion, but then I would have to add the `@Html.Action()` to every view manually.

Comment: Only in your master layout

Comment: Refer also [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/164/nested-layout-pages-with-razor) for implementing nested layouts

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.